# Advanced multithreading - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't come across work that requires much experience with `multi-threading`. So I was wondering if anyone know of site (open source project) where I could take look at real world examples of some heavy duty code that takes care of `thread pools` solves `deadlock` situation, uses `nonblocking algorithms`, `reentrant locks`, `join-fork`, `futures-callables` well you get the idea.

To be more specific I'm looking for J2EE and MOM integration and messaging used between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These use everything you have mentioned and have the benfit of being quite well documented from a design point of view too.

[JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/), [Jboss Cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache) and its successor [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan)

Comment: Tomcat uses a lot of thread as well

Comment: [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) is another JBoss project that is J2EE/MOM and uses lots of concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at the original Java java.util.concurrent package. That must be state of the art.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of any particular site that goes through this with anything other than a trivial example (I'm guessing you've already gone through the various tutorials out there).

My recommendation would be:

1. Start a project of your own, if you haven't already
2. Get on GitHub and search around for multi-threaded Java apps that look reasonably stable/large/complex

Option 2 will, at least, give you some real-world experience and let you see what multithreaded code in a production system actually looks like (i.e. because it will be code that has been worked, and reworked by real programmers, solving a real problem).